# Why $\langle w, w\rangle _1 = \langle w, w\rangle_2$ $\forall w \in W$ in a linear space $W$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Why $\langle w, w\rangle_1 = \langle w, w\rangle_2$, $\forall w \in W$ in a linear space $W$?

Here, $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_1 \neq \langle\cdot, \cdot\rangle_2$

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand the formulation of your question which  is "why f_1(w)=f_2(w)"... what else...

Comment: I think you mean $\sqrt2<w,w>_1=<w,w>_2$

Comment: Are $\langle\cdot, \cdot\rangle_1$ and $\langle\cdot, \cdot\rangle_2$ two different inner products on $W$? If so, the statement does not hold: take the standard inner product $\langle\cdot, \cdot\rangle$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\alpha\langle\cdot, \cdot\rangle$, $\alpha > 0$ for the other one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't true. For any non-zero vector $w$, if you plug it into the inner product you should not get zero.

However, if you define: $\langle v ,w \rangle_2 := 2\langle v,w \rangle_1$, then this is an inner product (you can check all the rules or just notice that each entry of the matrix for the inner product has been multiplied by $\sqrt{2}$) but if $\langle , \rangle_1$ is an inner product then plugging in any non-zero $w$ should give a contradiction since $\langle w, w \rangle_1 \neq 0$ so
$2\langle w, w \rangle_1 = \langle w, w \rangle_1$ so $2 = 1$.
So, we get a contradiction if the vector space is over a field like $\mathbb{R}$ and we can easily cook up a counterexample for every vector space.

Actually, if the vector space is over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, one can use [the polarization identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity) to prove that if $\langle w, w \rangle_1 = \langle w, w \rangle_2$ for all $w \in V$, then they are identical.